# Does this coding style belong to an older version of C++?

Tags: c++

I come across this code in my older books.  I tried to run it in Visual Studio 2019, but it gave me an error:

> volume function does not take zero arguments

Is this because the code is old, or the code is wrong?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Cylinder
{
private:
    const double pi = 3.14;
    double r, h;
public:
    void ro(double radius) {
        r = radius;
    }
    void ho(double height) {
        h = height;
    }
    double volume(double r, double h)
    {
        return pi * r * r * h;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cylinder s;
    s.ro(1);
    s.ho(2);
    cout << s.volume();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is wrong. The `volume` function is declared to take two `double` arguments and the C++ compiler expects it to be called that way.

I'm not aware of any C++ compiler of any age that would accept that code.

It looks like maybe the function is trying to use the member variables `r` and `h`, in which case you should probably remove the parameters from the declaration of `volume`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is wrong.

When calling a function, you must pass in as many values as there are parameters declared.  You can't skip parameters, unless they are declared with default values, which is not the case here.

Given the way `main()` is using `Cylinder` in this example, the 2 input parameters need to be removed completely, since they are *shadowing* the `r` and `h` class members that are being set by the `ro()` and `ho()` methods.

```
double volume()
{
    return pi * r * r * h;
}
```

Now the call to `cout << s.volume();` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code is wrong.
If you had default argument on the method.
E.g something like this:

```
double volume(double r = 0, double h = 0)
{
    return pi * r * r * h;
}
```

It would work when you call it without parameters.